# ALAMOFIRE post request image download and binding in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, alamofire

I need to download images I created a `alamofire` post request with parameter i dont have any problem in that . After that i need to download the image url from the Json response generated, I dont know how to download the image url from json and keep that in a array , after that have to download the inage from the url need to bind it in a image view of `collectionView` . I dont have any idea about how to take the image url from the json response then keep that in a array , then have to download the image bind it in a `collectionView`. Please help me
I have updated the json response for my post request. please give me a solution. I can get the below response in console.

```
(   {
ActualPrice = 0;
AssuredTitle = "<null>";
CashBackAmount = 0;
CashBackDiscountPercentage = 0;
Code = "";
Cost = "<null>";
CreateDate = "<null>";
CustomSize = 0;
Delivery = "<null>";
DeliveryDate = "<null>";
DeliveryDays = "<null>";
Designer = "<null>";
Discount = "<null>";
DiscountCost = "<null>";
DispatchDateDisplay = "<null>";
Exclusive = "<null>";
Gender = "<null>";
HasReadyMadeColor = 0;
HasReadyMadeSizes = 0;
ID = 41;
ImageUrl = "https://images.cbazaar.com/images/aqua-blue-georgette-abaya-isbs1805991-u.jpg";
Is7DD = "<null>";
IsCustomizable = 0;
IsExclusive = 0;
IsFree = "<null>";
IsFreeShipping = 0;
IsInWishlist = 0;
IsLookUp = 0;
IsNew = 0;
IsProductAnimation = 0;
IsReadyToShip = 0;
LargeImageUrl = "<null>";
ListingImage = "<null>";
LowerLargeImage = "<null>";
LowerThumbImage = "<null>";
MoneyFactor = "<null>";
MoneyOffFactor = "<null>";
Name = "Islamic wear";
OfferImageUrl = "<null>";
OldPrice = 0;
OutOfStock = 0;
PDUrl = "<null>";
ProductBigLink = "<null>";
ProductCollectionReference = "<null>";
ProductHisImage = "<null>";
ProductSaleCycle = 0;
ProductType = 168;
ProductV2VRatio = 0;
PromotionTypeID = "<null>";
Promotions = "<null>";
PromotionsIcon = "<null>";
Rating = "<null>";
SalePrice = "<null>";
ShowOldPrice = 0;
SizeChart = "<null>";
SuperClassification = "<null>";
TypeGroup = "<null>";
TypeShortCode = "<null>";
UpperLargeImage = "<null>";
UpperThumbImage = "<null>";
VendorType = "<null>";
VisitCount = 0;
})
```

Complete ViewController File

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class EthnoVogueDesignConsultationViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var header_scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pagecontroller: UIPageControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var step_label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var segmented_View: UIView!


    @IBOutlet weak var segmented_Control: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var stylistView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var categorycollectionview: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pagecontrollerview: UIView!



    let image_array = ["slider1","slider2","slider1","slider2"]

    let name_label = ["Salwar kameez","saree", "Anarkali", "Leghenga"]

    static var deepLinkingFlag:Int = 0
    static var deepLinkingFlagAfterKilling:Int = 0
    var httpObj = HTTPHelper()
    var apiRequestParameters:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


    var dictResult: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

    // var imageCache = [String:UIImage]()

    //Array of images from the URL

    var imageArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        globalConstants.deepLinkingFlagAfterKilling = 0
        globalConstants.deepLinkingFlag = 0

        apiclass()
       // imagedownload()

        //View which holds the stylist Name

            stylistView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 232/255, blue: 232/255, alpha: 1)

        pagecontrollerview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 232/255, blue: 232/255, alpha: 1)

        //Label with holds the step 1

            step_label.layer.borderWidth = 2
            step_label.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
            stylistView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            step_label.layer.shadowOpacity = 4
            step_label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

        //Customising the segmented control with background color and tint color, font size

            segmented_Control.tintColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1)
            segmented_Control.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            segmented_Control.layer.cornerRadius = 20
           // let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
            let font =  UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
            segmented_Control.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: font],
                                                 for: .normal)






        let cellSize = CGSize(width:250 , height:400)

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = cellSize
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
        categorycollectionview.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)

        categorycollectionview.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
        categorycollectionview.delegate = self
        categorycollectionview.dataSource = self


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.header_scrollView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.frame.width, height:225)
        let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.header_scrollView.frame.width
        let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.header_scrollView.frame.height
        header_scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        //set image to the particular image in uiscrollview

        let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
        imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "slider2")
        let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
        imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "slider1")


        //Adding subview for the scrollview

        self.header_scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
        self.header_scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)

        //setting size of the content view

        self.header_scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.header_scrollView.frame.width * 4, height:self.header_scrollView.frame.height)

        //header scroll view delegate selection

        self.header_scrollView.delegate = self
        self.pagecontroller.currentPage = 0 

        // time interval to move the slide show

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(moveToNextPage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        //step label for rounded corners

        step_label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        step_label.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0



        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(EthnoVogueDesignConsultationViewController.deepLinking(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "deepLinking"), object: nil)





    }



    @objc func deepLinking(_ notification:Notification){
        print("its here")
        //   globalConstants.isSortCleared = 0
        if(globalConstants.deepLinkingFlag == 1){
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
            //            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"catalog") as? CatalogController
            //            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: false)
        }
        else if(globalConstants.deepLinkingFlag == 2){
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
            //            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"productDetails") as? ProductDetailViewController
            //            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: false)
        }
        else if(globalConstants.deepLinkingFlag == 3){
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
            //            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ols") as? OLSViewController
            //            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: false)
        }
        else if(globalConstants.deepLinkingFlag == 4){
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
            //            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"home") as? HomeController
            //            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: false)
        }
        else if(globalConstants.deepLinkingFlag == 5){
            //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        }
        else if(globalConstants.deepLinkingFlag == 6){
            //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
        }
        else if(globalConstants.deepLinkingFlag == 7){
            //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        }
    }


    // move to next image image view in file

    @objc func moveToNextPage (){

        let pageWidth:CGFloat = self.header_scrollView.frame.width
        let maxWidth:CGFloat = pageWidth * 2
        let contentOffset:CGFloat = self.header_scrollView.contentOffset.x

        var slideToX = contentOffset + pageWidth

        if  contentOffset + pageWidth == maxWidth
        {
            slideToX = 0
        }
        self.header_scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x:slideToX, y:0, width:pageWidth, height:self.header_scrollView.frame.height), animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //scrollView Method for chaning the page control while swiping the image

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pagenumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        pagecontroller.currentPage = Int(pagenumber)
    }




    //CollectionView for Categories image 

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch segmented_Control.selectedSegmentIndex {

        case 0:
            return imageArray.count

        case 1:
            return 10

        default:
            break
        }
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imagecell", for: indexPath) as! CategorySegmentCollectionViewCell

        let url = NSURL(string: self.imageArray[indexPath.item])!

        Cell.category_image.af_setImage(withURL: url as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "noimage.png"), filter: nil, imageTransition: .noTransition, runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: nil)

        switch segmented_Control.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:

//            let img : UIImage = UIImage(named:"pink")!
//
//            Cell.category_image.image = img
         //   Cell.category_name_label.text = name_label[indexPath.item]
            break


        case 1:

//            let img : UIImage = UIImage(named:"dark")!
//            Cell.category_image.image = img
//               Cell.category_name_label.text = "condition"
            break
        default:
            break
        }


        //let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "brandCell", for: indexPath) as! BrandCollectionViewCell
        // use this to download images


        return Cell
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategorySegmentCollectionViewCell {
                cell.category_image.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1)
            }
        }
    }


     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategorySegmentCollectionViewCell {
                cell.category_image.transform = .identity
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        switch segmented_Control.selectedSegmentIndex{

        case 0:
            if (collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategorySegmentCollectionViewCell) != nil {
                self.segmented_Control.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 1)
                segmented_Control.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
                collectionView.reloadData()
                //print(cell)
            }
            break

        case 1:
            if (collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategorySegmentCollectionViewCell) != nil {

                self.segmented_Control.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 2)
                let categoryTaskVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fabrics") as! FabricsViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryTaskVC, animated: true)

             }

            break


        default:
            break


        }



    }





    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if(segmented_Control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

          self.segmented_Control.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 1)
            self.segmented_Control.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 2)


        }
    }





 @IBAction func segmented_tapped_action(_ sender: Any) {

        categorycollectionview.reloadData()



    }


    func apiclass(){

        if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authToken") == nil){
            self.httpObj.getAuthToken()
        }
        else if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authExpireDate") != nil && Date().compare((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authExpireDate") as? Date)!) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending){
            globalConstants.prefs.setValue(nil, forKey: "authToken")
            self.httpObj.getAuthToken()
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authToken") != nil){
                var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: globalConstants.tokenUrl as URL)
                let authToken:String = (globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "authToken") as? String)!
                request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: globalConstants.tokenUrl as URL)
                request.addValue("Bearer \(authToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                request.addValue(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Device-ID")
                request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "UUID") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Unique-ID")
                request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "countryCode") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Country-Code")
                request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "currencyCode") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Currency-Code")
                request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "currencySymbol") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Currency-Symbol")
                request.addValue(String(stringInterpolationSegment: (globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "currencyFactor"))!), forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Currency-Factor")
                request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "appSource") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-App-Source")
                request.addValue(globalConstants.appVersion, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-App-Version")
                request.addValue(String(stringInterpolationSegment: (globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? Int)!), forHTTPHeaderField: "X-EStore-ID")

                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
                if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "userEmail") != nil){
                    request.addValue((globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "userEmail") as? String)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Email")
                }
                if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "userId") != nil){
                    request.addValue(String(stringInterpolationSegment: (globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "userId"))!), forHTTPHeaderField: "X-User-ID")
                }

                print(self.apiRequestParameters)

                var requestParameters:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
                requestParameters = [

                    "mode" : "design",
                    "productGroup" : 0

                ]

                print(requestParameters)

                request.url = globalConstants.ESDCUrl as URL

                self.httpObj.sendRequest("POST", requestDict: requestParameters, request: request as URLRequest, completion: { (result, error)  in
                    print(result!)



                    if(error == nil){

                        guard let json = result as! [[String:Any]]? else{

                            return

                        }

                        print("Response \(json)")


                        for images in json
                        {
                            if let ImageUrl = images["ImageUrl"] as? String
                            {
                                self.imageArray.append(ImageUrl)

                            }
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.categorycollectionview.reloadData()
                            }

                        }


                       // self.dictResult = result as! NSDictionary

                       // self.categorycollectionview.reloadData()




                        //self.collectionView.reloadData()

//                        let requestDataDict:NSDictionary = incomingRequetArray[0] as! NSDictionary
//                        let newDict: NSURL = requestDataDict.object(forKey: "ImageUrl") as? NSDictionary
//

                    }
                    else{
                        let alert = UIAlertView()
                        alert.isHidden = true
                        alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
                        alert.message = globalConstants.apiErrorMessage
                        alert.show()
                    }
                })
            }
        })

    }



//typealaising the headerscrollview to the view controller

private typealias Header_scrollView = EthnoVogueDesignConsultationViewController

// extending the header_scrollview
extension Header_scrollView

{
    func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
        // Test the offset and calculate the current page after scrolling ends
        let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
        let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1
        // Change the indicator
        self.pagecontroller.currentPage = Int(currentPage);

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            // self.startButton.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: so your question is you just want to do download the images

Comment: I need to download the image from the JSON response and keep it in a array, by using that array i need to bind the image in UICollection view cell @V_rohit

Comment: okay thats not a big problem.... Did you heard about the alamofireImage pod?

Comment: let me know if this is useful or not?